# Safest way to get last record ID from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008 and higher what is the best/safest/most correct way

1. to retrieve the ID (based on autoincrementing primary key) out of the database table?
2. to retrieve the value of the last row of some other column (like, SELECT TOP 1 FROM Table ORDER BY DESC)?

Comment: A slight complication is whether you want the last ID issued that is still in the database, or the last ID issued - the record could of been added and removed. In which case using a max / top etc will fail to get you that id.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Safest way will be to output or return the scope_identity() within the procedure inserting the row, and then retrieve the row based on that ID. Use of @@Identity is to be avoided since you can get the incorrect ID when triggers are in play.

Any technique of asking for the maximum value / top 1 suffers a race condition where 2 people adding at the same time, would then get the same ID back when they looked for the highest ID.

Comment: I read this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx about @@identity and scope_identity and it seems your answer is the most appropriate one. I have two additional questions before accepting the answer - if there is no insert before and we request scope_identity(), will it return anything? And another, if I was to create business keys in my application and then store them into the table, and I want them do derive from identity, is it fine to query for scope_identity()?

Comment: If you fail to insert anything scope_identity() will return null; once you have returned scope_identity() and have the identity field, you can use it in queries to return to that row for whatever purposes you decide.

Comment: scope_identity will return the last successfully inserted id within the current scope, whether that was the last attempt or not, whether it was the same TABLE or not.  output inserted.ID into @tableId is much more reliable at getting the id if the table doesn't have a trigger.

Answer (score 29):

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Table')
```

You can use one of these examples:

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
WHERE ID = (
    SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Table'))

SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE ID = (
    SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Table)

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

But the first one will be more efficient because no index scan is needed (if you have index on Id column).

The second one solution is equivalent to the third (both of them need to scan table to get max id).

Comment: second one is wrong, If any rows deleted that will give wrong answer.

Answer (score 28):

```
1.  SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Table
```

Comment: Thanks! best, just one :)

Answer (score 15):

You can try:

```
SELECT id FROM your_table WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM your_table)
```

Where `id` is a primary key of the `your_table`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This Question already has an accepted answer and in Addition ist 4 Years old. In this case there is no additional answer needend.

Comment: @j_s_stack ,  he gave a better answer , so why you opine that?

Comment: This is just a copy paste answer. Please remove it.

Comment: Not sure why this answer posted 5 years after a nearly identical answer below has more upvotes, but I have to agree with j_s_stack and @reaz-murshed.

Answer (score 5):

I think this one will also work:

> SELECT * FROM  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0 , 1

Answer (score 4):

One more way -

```
select * from <table> where  id=(select max(id) from <table>)
```

Also you can check on this link -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx

Comment: that's one more way but I am not sure if it doesn't suffer from the same possible issues that SELECT TOP..does. Would be nice if someone with deeper SQL knowledge comments on both solutions how reliable they are in a high volume usage scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

And if you mean select the ID of the last record inserted, its

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT LAST(row_name) FROM table_name

Comment: This question already contains multiple answers and an accepted answer. Can you explain (by editing your answer) where your answer differs from the other answers? Also know that Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.