# Retrieve id of record just inserted into a Java DB (Derby) database

Tags: sql, jdbc, javadb

I am connecting to a Java DB database with JDBC and want to retrieve the id (which is on auto increment) of the last record inserted.

I see this is a common question, but I see [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422168/safest-way-to-get-last-record-id-from-a-table) using for example MS SQL Server, what is the equivalent for Java DB?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No need to use a DBMS specific SQL for that.

That's what [getGeneratedKeys()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29) is for.

When [preparing your statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29) you pass the name(s) of the auto-generated columns which you can then retrieve using getGeneratedKeys()

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
     "insert into some_table (col1, col2, ..) values (....)", 
      new String[] { "ID_COLUMN"} ); 

pstmt.executeUpdate();

ResultSet rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys(); // will return the ID in ID_COLUMN
```

Note that column names are case sensitive in this case (in Derby and many other DBMS). 
`new String[] { "ID_COLUMN"}`  is something different than `new String[] { "id_column"}`

---

Alternatively you can also use:

```
connection.prepareStatement("INSERT ...", PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

Comment: I just wanna confirm this, thought I'm 99% sure, will this still return the intended auto-generated column value even if multiple insert statements have been executed in the time between inserting and fetching column value using `getGeneratedKeys()`?

Comment: Doesn't work for me, it also looks like [JDBC doesn't fully support Derby's identity columns](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/activejdbc-group/aU1fRiRAffs/XMIE3OOvzRkJ)? I get an exception saying that my table doesn't have an auto-generated column named 'id', which it clearly does :)

Comment: Anyway I solved by using `PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` instead of the string array as the second argument in the PreparedStatement. (I'm pretty sure my problem was not a typo if anyone was wondering).

Comment: @Alex: I am 100% the above code works with Apache Derby. Your link is for a group that deals with ActiveJDBC - which is an ORM (="Obfuscated Relational Model") framework **on top** of JDBC. "JDBC" itself doesn't support anything - it's just a specification that needs to be implemented by the vendor of the JDBC driver. That has nothing to do with the JDBC driver Derby is providing. If _that_ framework doesn't work with Derby, it's neither "JDBC's" fault nor Derby's fault. Maybe you didn't specify the column correctly, e.g. `new String[] { "ID"}` is something else than `new String[] { "id"}`

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for the clarification. And yes apparently column names are case sensitive, I was sure they were working both ways, thanks again @a_horse_with_no_name. I'll leave my comment anyways just to provide a more general way to get the columns.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to get what you're looking for using the IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL function. ([Derby Reference](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/refderby.pdf))

This function is supposed to return "the most recently assigned value of an identity column for a connection, where the assignment occurred as a result of a single row INSERT statement using a VALUES clause."

It's worth noting that this function will return DECIMAL(31,0), regardless of the actual data type of the corresponding identity column.

Also, this **only** works for single row inserts that contain a VALUES clause.

Answer (score 1):

For those who have issues getting the generated autoincrement id like I used to for Java Derby, my answer can be of help.

```
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO xx(Name) VALUES ('Joe')", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()) {
  int autoKey = rs.getInt(1); //this is the auto-generated key for your use
}
```

Answer copied from [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24778986/Get-last-ID-after-identity-insert-in-Derby-DB.htmlhttps://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24778986/Get-last-ID-after-identity-insert-in-Derby-DB.html)