# Get the ID of the record I have just inserted in Derby DB

Tags: java, derby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieve id of record just inserted into a Java DB (Derby) database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894754/retrieve-id-of-record-just-inserted-into-a-java-db-derby-database)

I have a table in a Derby database with a column created:

```
id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
```

How do I get the id of the last record inserted?
How can I know what is the id of the record I have just inserted?

Comment: This has nothing to do with java-ee. Changed tag to `java`

Answer (score 1):

Java's Statement class has getGeneratedKeys(), which is designed to provide that information:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys()

Answer (score 1):

the IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() function should be your friend: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefidentityvallocal.html

Comment: ... although this binds you to Derby.

Answer (score 1):

See following SO question:
[Retrieve id of record just inserted into a Java DB (Derby) database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894754/retrieve-id-of-record-just-inserted-into-a-java-db-derby-database)