# java.sql.SQLException: Table 'CONNECTIONS' does not have an auto-generated column named 'connection_id'

Tags: java, javadb

I'm trying to retreive the connection_id column while inserting into Connections table.  I have a table being generated at the start of the application like this with the column_id being auto generated.

```
CREATE TABLE connections (connection_ID INT not null primary key GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), 
connection_name VARCHAR(100) unique not null, user_name VARCHAR(100) not null, password VARCHAR (100) not null, server_url 
VARCHAR(100) not null, port_number VARCHAR(10) not null),
```

I'm using the following statement to retrieve the liat of connection_ids

```
PreparedStatement stmt = dbconn.prepareStatement(insertString, new String[] {"connection_id"});
```

But I get the following exception even though my connection_id is auto-generated,

```
java.sql.SQLException: Table 'CONNECTIONS' does not have an auto-generated column named 'connection_id'.
```

Comment: Which database are you using? I've seen some databases that do not support auto-incrementing ID's in this fashion. That might explain this result.

Comment: I'm using "Java DB" and the auto generate works if I take out the new String[] {Connection ID} and the getGeneratedKeys() functions off the code!

Comment: Does it work with connection_ID and/or CONNECTION_ID? Maybe Java DB treats it case-sensitive

Comment: No, I've tried all possible combinations but it simple doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` instead of `new String[] {"ID_colname"}` - see a_horse_with_no_name's answer to this question:

[Retrieve id of record just inserted into a Java DB (Derby) database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894754/retrieve-id-of-record-just-inserted-into-a-java-db-derby-database)

For example:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("insert .... ", PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ps.executeUpdate();
ResultSet results = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
```

I have just had the same problem (8 years later!) and 'this works for me'.

I don't know why the `new String[] {"ID_colname"}` doesn't work, but at least there is this alternative to try.

Comment: Extremely weird! The documentation specifically states to write the column name of the auto generated id! Your suggestion did the trick though, thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

I do not have much experience with Java DB, but I hope this will help.
Maybe what you need is to make the auto generated keys returnable. Check the [Java DB Reference Manual](http://download.oracle.com/javadb/10.5.1.1/ref/ref-single.html#crefjavstateautogen) and the [Connection class definition](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)