# Spawned process ID

Tags: batch-file, kill-process, child-process

Is there something similar to bash `$!` moniker in windows to access the last process id that I can use in `"TASKKILL /F /T /PID $pid"`? I see that [Microsoft SQL has @@IDENTITY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3422222/1083704) to get the id of the last created object. Does batch shell has a command for the same purpose?

Comment: Don't think you can.  But there are some insights here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807794/how-to-capture-the-pid-of-a-process-when-launching-it-in-dos

Comment: @DavidCandy Do not make programs simple and reliable. Make them complex and doing windows instead what you need. Thanks, I have got the Windows spirit.