# Trigger optimisation

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

How can I optimise this trigger? It works perfectly, but I think it can be improved:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_request_missions_after_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `request_missions`
 FOR EACH ROW
IF ((SELECT id FROM request_missions ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)+1) >= 1  AND 
   ((SELECT id FROM request_missions ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)+1) <= 9 THEN
        SET New.rm_number = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%y'), '-',
            CONCAT('00000',(SELECT id FROM request_missions ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)+1));
    END IF
```

The results will be in the `rm_number` column, like:

for id >=1 and id <= 9

```
19-000001
19-000002
...
19-000009
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Be aware that questions about code improvement -- when the code is working -- are more suitable to be asked on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't believe this does work - id = 1 will acquire null since the before trigger cannot  possibly know that id 1 will be allocated for the first insert because it is allocated after the before trigger. Also anything with an id > 8 will acquire null. Anything between 2 and 8 (inclusive) will be allocated a number which matches the id(ie 19-000002 to 19-000008). The only safe way to do what you appear to want, imo, is do this with a separate update statement after the inserts possibly as part of a transaction.

Comment: Thank you P.Salmon , Ok, I have updated the code above , my concern is how to replace the expression
(SELECT id FROM request_missions ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1) +1)
by another shorter like a variable for exemple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks M. Bill Karwin the code is now more clean
For the problème of year I changed it to '%Y' .
The code is now :

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_request_missions_after_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `request_missions`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE next_id INT;
  SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id),0) + 1 INTO next_id FROM request_missions;
  IF next_id BETWEEN 1 AND 9 THEN
    SET NEW.rm_number = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y'), '-', '00000', next_id);
  ELSEIF next_id BETWEEN 10 AND 99 THEN
    SET NEW.rm_number = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y'), '-', '0000', next_id);
  ELSEIF next_id BETWEEN 100 AND 999 THEN
    SET NEW.rm_number = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y'), '-', '000', next_id);
  ELSEIF next_id BETWEEN 1000 AND 9999 THEN
    SET NEW.rm_number = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y'), '-', '00', next_id);
  ELSEIF next_id BETWEEN 10000 AND 99999 THEN
    SET NEW.rm_number = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y'), '-', '0', next_id);
  ELSEIF next_id BETWEEN 100000 AND 999999 THEN
    SET NEW.rm_number = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y'), '-', next_id);
  END IF;
END
```

> Warning: this suffers from a race condition. For example, if two
>   sessions are inserting to the table at the same time, they might both
>   read the same next_id.

Is there a solution to this issue, knowing that the purpose of this trigger is to add a number in the format 'YYYY-ID' for each line added.
YYYY: is the current Year
ID : is the id of the current row formated as shown in the trigger

Comment: One solution to  race condition is to lock the table before you INSERT, so there cannot be two concurrent sessions trying to insert.

Comment: Another solution is to use another table or something outside the database to produce incrementing numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion for using a local variable instead of repeating your subquery three times. You said that was your concern.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_request_missions_after_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `request_missions`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE next_id INT;
  SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id),0) + 1 INTO next_id FROM request_missions;
  IF next_id BETWEEN 1 AND 9 THEN
    SET NEW.rm_number = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%y'), '-', '00000', next_id);
  END IF;
END
```

Warning: this suffers from a race condition. For example, if two sessions are inserting to the table at the same time, they might both read the same `next_id`.

Also as @P.Salmon commented above, the results are undefined if `next_id` is > 9. I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

You might want to allow longer numbers, and pad them to a fixed length with zeroes:

```
LPAD(next_id, 6, '0')
```

See the manual on the [LPAD()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) function.

I used `COALESCE(MAX(id),0)` to make sure at least there's one non-NULL value returned, in case the table has zero rows.

This is also concerning:

```
DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%y')
```

A two-digit year will roll over to `00` in 81 years. This is exactly how the Y2K problem was created! I know you won't be working on the code by then, so you might not care. But you should always code as if the person who ends up maintaining your code is a violent psychopath who knows where you live.

---

Re your new code posted in another answer:

This is a better solution for handling the next_id numbers up to 999,999.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_request_missions_after_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `request_missions`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE next_id INT;
  SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id),0) + 1 INTO next_id FROM request_missions;
  IF next_id < 1000000 THEN
    SET NEW.rm_number = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%y'), '-', LPAD(next_id, 6, '0'));
  ELSE
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'RM Number has reached capacity'
  END IF;
END
```

The race condition issue is different, and there's no solution while you are using `MAX(id)` to find the last id. The problem is that you might have more than one client inserting to the table concurrently. Each client's session will read the same value for `MAX(id)` and use it.

You should read about [Race Conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

What you really need is some way of using an `AUTO_INCREMENT` value that generates new unique values in a thread-safe manner, and copy the value into your `rm_number`.

Unfortunately, there's no way to do this in a trigger. During a BEFORE INSERT trigger, the new AUTO_INCREMENT value is not generated yet. During an AFTER INSERT trigger, you can't modify `NEW.rm_number` because the insert is already done. I wrote about this in the past:

- [Concatenating a string and primary key Id while inserting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331194/concatenating-a-string-and-primary-key-id-while-inserting/23331246#23331246)
- [Two autoincrements columns or autoincrement and same value in other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324201/two-autoincrements-columns-or-autoincrement-and-same-value-in-other-column/40643554#40643554)

Comment: Thanks M. Bill Karwin

Comment: Thank's M. Bill Karwin the trigger Work perfectly 
I Just a added `SQLSTATE` to ` `SIGNAL '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'RM Number has reached capacity'  `
I think it is not wrong !!

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot `SQLSTATE`. I've corrected the example in my answer.

Comment: However, I still get the impression you don't understand the race condition issue. That is NOT solved by my example.

Comment: I think i have understand the Race Condition, but you have said there is no solution for this issue with triggers.
berhaps updating the value of rm_ number after inserting data is the solution ? what you think ?

Comment: Yes. I wrote about that in other posts to which I linked.

Comment: Please if you can make link  ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I provided two links at the end of my answer.

Comment: Ok that's right 
Thank you very mutch M. Bill Karxin for all helps

Comment: M. Bill , Finaly i decided to resolve my problem out side the database using PHP Laravel framwork. and i solved it