# How do I give a non primary key an auto incrementing value by default using Spring JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I'm creating a `Queue` object.

```
public class Queue {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "queue_number", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long queueNumber;
...
}
```

It has the `id` field as it's primary key. But as for queueNumber, I want it to auto increment like the id field. The code above just doesn't work. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do you want MySQL to generate the values? MySQL will not support two auto-increment columns in the same table. No way to do it, even with triggers. If you can write Java code to allocate new unique values you could insert them, but then it's not auto.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/38324201/20860 but that's about PHP & Laravel, not Java & Spring.

Comment: `MySQL will not support two auto-increment columns in the same table.` welp this is pretty much the answer I'm looking for. bummer. thanks!

Comment: [MariaDB-10.3+ has Sequences](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequences/) that can be used like auto_increment values that don't have a limit on the number of them in a table. `CREATE SEQUENCE seq_t_i INCREMENT 1 START WITH 1` and the sequence can be used as the default value in a table `CREATE TABLE t(
i integer DEFAULT nextval(seq_t_i), j integer );`